# How to remove default selected date in DatePicker materialUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using date pickers in my project https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker, I have used a calendar with no year selection. When I open the calendar by clicking a textbox for the very first time, I don't want today's date to be selected and want it to be empty like this ([show calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGUuh.png)). But if I select any date and close the calendar then the selected date should remain and it should not get cleared. Can anyone help me how do I achieve this??

```
const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

<DatePicker
  disableToolbar
  variant="inline"
  label="Only calendar"
  helperText="No year selection"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
 />
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you are already trying to the question?

Comment: i have added sample code, i have set selectedDate state variable to null but till date shows as selected. could u please provide any solution?

Answer (score 4):

as you did not provide sample code, I think you have set the state variable default to current date, like as given in the example:

```
const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());
```

I would suggest to try by setting it to `null` eg:

```
const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but it doesn't works it still shows default date selected in green color on calendar

Answer (score 1):

We can also apply this way, It is also suitable if we are not handling the date field with useState.

```
value={value ? dayjs(value) : null}
```

If the value exists it will show the selected date otherwise it will be set the value as null.